# Checking the data of returned children in pool.map_async()

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

Let's say I am trying to find a special number from 0-100000. Here is my program to do so:

```
def checkNum(num):
    if num == 43582:
        print('Found!')
        return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':

    thingsToCheck = []
    for i in range(0, someLargeNumber)
        thingsToCheck.append(randomInteger())

    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    answers = pool.map_async(checkNum, thingsToCheck)
    answers.wait()
    answers = nodesPopulated.get()
    if True in answers:
        print('Answer was found!')
    else:
        print('No answer :(')
```

There are two options of output:

```
Found!
Found!
...
Found!
Answer was found!
```

For `Found!` can be printed `len(thingsToCheck)` times or

`No answer :(`

But with the sole purpose of checking if we found the number, it seems pointless to find it over and over again when finding it just once is what I am trying to do. So is there a way to loop over the results **as they come in** and then terminate the other children? I am hoping to do something like this: (pseudo)

```
answers = pool.map_async(checkNum, thingsToCheck)
while newAnswer has come:            #run this loop when a child has finished
    answers = nodesPopulated.get()   #hopefully returns list of return values or None
    for answer in answers:
        if answer == complete:
            if True in answer:
                print('Answer was found!')
                answers.killChildren()
                quit()
print('No answer :(')
```